# A reference list for html, like used in markdown for links and images

Tags: html, reference

One of the most important things making markdown readable, is the reference list, containing the urls of links and images, which then appear in the visible text as `[name_link]` as a very calm and readable substitution for the real link in the ref list.( `[name_link](https://example.com)` )

I've always admired this technique. My question is: can someone show me a way to do this in html in stead of md? If possible without heavy coding, preferably just html/css ;) I don't mind reading short tags in a html source text, like `<b>,<p>,<h2>, etc..`, but it would be great if we could get rid of the longer ones for links and images!****

Gratefully!
bert

[Edit April 22] Maybe I should explain a little better. I'm working on a little project for webwriters, trying to improve the experience of writing in html directly as much as possible, so that , once the original fears for html are gone, it becomes a viable alternative to wysiwyg or markdown. Goal is to make it even easier than those... I'm a professional amateur... If interested, see [featherweb](https://featherweb.neocities.org)

Comment: You think that `a` and `img` are *long*?

Comment: I did not explain well, so you misunderstood. The tags themselves are of course short, but once they"re filled: <a href="" target="" class="">link_name</a> they tend to become huge and they make reading the source more difficult. For example linking to this page would be: <pre><code> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71926002/a-reference-list-for-html-like-used-in-markdown-for-links-and-images">see stackoverflow</a></code></pre> Hope I made it clearer now